# How to restore lost contacts/address book?

Tags: time-machine, restore, contacts

I suddenly have only 2 contacts in my Contacts! I have a MacBook Pro, am using OS 10.9.2. Following instructions from another answer, I looked for Address book folder in the library/App. Support folder and it is not there. So couldn't proceed.

In Time Machine yesterday it shows "Address book Forwarder". But I don't know what that means, but perhaps it had something to do with my loss? Does this mean I sent my address book somewhere? Looks like it!

I don't know how to use Time Machine to restore my contacts. The restore button is grayed out. Nothing happens when I double click the Contacts folder there, so I don't know how to copy the content, nor where to paste it since I do not have that folder in the Library that you mention.

I do not use iCloud. I do have files backed up on an external drive, but don't know how to use it.

I know this sounds like a mess and it seems to be.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Time Machine, just open the Contacts app, and THEN go to Time Machine (Click on the menubar icon / Enter Time Machine)

[image: Enter Time Machine]

Once there, you can "travel in time" to an older date and find the missing contact. This is where you select the contact and click "Restore".

[image: Time Machine Working]

You don't need to restore a folder or file, but the contact (in the Contacts app) itself.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Some of my contacts lost their phone numbers. I chose a contact, found the previous, more complete entry, and hit restore. It exited Time Machine and asked me if I wanted to import the new card. I hit "Import" but the card didn't change. It was still missing the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

I also do not use iCloud.  My phone was so full (especially documents & data which seem impossible to delete without restoring the phone) that I ended up backing up my phone and restoring it to factory (with the new iOS8).  Anyway, since iTunes won't let me pick and choose what I want to restore from the backup, I lost all my contacts.
I went to my phone, settings, iCloud and turned the on CONTACTS only and a few seconds later, all of my contacts appeared.  I'm not sure (because I have so many) if it's maybe from a prior life when I tried to use iCloud or where it came from but it looks like everyone's there.
It's very simple to try at least.  Hope it helps.